# Does this proposition really prove that n is not a prime?

Tags: number-theory

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense because I can't think of any number that meet that criteria for the number 4, which is not prime.

a must be different from b, right?

http://s13.postimage.org/3ti78qiav/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 2):

No, not necessarily different. $4=2\cdot 2$. And $4|4$ but $4\not|2$.

Comment: How is 4 not divisible by 2?

Comment: Ah, I see. n can't divide a. I thought the notation meant a can't divide n.

Answer (score 1):

It proves: the integer $\rm\,p>1\,$ is prime (i.e. irreducible) if it satisfies PDP = Prime Divisor Property (i.e. $\rm\,p\,$ divides a product $\rm\Rightarrow p$ divides some factor). Below is a proof that clarifies this inference.

**Theorem** $\ $ In the following, $\rm\ (1)\:\Rightarrow\:(2)\iff (3)$

$\rm(1)\ \ \ a\ \ |\ \ bc\  \Rightarrow\  a\:|\:b\ \ or\ \ a\:|\:c\quad$ (Definition of $\rm\:a\:$ satisfies PDP = Prime Divisor Property)

$\rm(2)\ \ \ a=bc\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{a\:|\:b}\ \ or\ \ \color{#0a0}{a\:|\:c}\quad$ (Definition of $\rm\:a\:$ is prime, i.e. irreducible) $\ $ (alternative)

$\rm(3)\ \ \ a=bc\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{b\:|\:1}\ \ or\ \ \color{#c00}{c\:|\:1}\quad$ (Definition of $\rm\:a\:$ is prime, i.e. irreducible) $\ $ (classical)

**Proof** $\ \ \ (1\Rightarrow 2)\ \ $ If $\rm\: a = bc\:$ then $\rm\:a\:|\:bc\:$ so $\rm\:a\:|\:b\:$ or $\rm\:a\:|\:c\:$ by $(1).\:$ Thus PDP $\Rightarrow$ irreducible(alt).

$(2\!\!\iff\!\! 3)\ \ \ $ If $\rm\:a = bc\:$ then $\rm\:b/a = 1/c\:$ so $\rm\:\color{#c00}{a\:|\:b\iff c\:|\:1}.\:$ Similarly $\rm\:\color{#0a0}{a\:|\:c\iff b\:|\:1}.$

**Remark** $\, $ In general domains, invertibles (= divisors of $1)$ are called *units*, and nonunits satisfying the Prime Divisor Property $(1)$ are called *primes*, and elements satisfying $(2)$ or $(3)$ are called *atoms* or *irreducibles*. So the inference $(1\Rightarrow 2)$ says that a prime is an atom = irreducible. The converse, atoms are prime, holds iff factorizations into atoms are *unique* (up to order and unit factors), using the same proof as the classical proof that $\Bbb Z$ is a UFD (= Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic).

Comment: Hey, Math Gems is back!