# Is this proof of the converse of Euclid's Lemma correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As part of a homework assignment, I attempted to prove the **converse of Euclid's lemma** on my own. My proof follows.

***Theorem:*** Suppose that $n$ is some natural number with the property that if $n$ divides $ab$, then $n$ divides at least one of $a$, $b$. Then $n$ is prime.

***Proof:*** By contradiction.

Let $n$ be the smallest natural number that divides $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Then, by Euclid's lemma, either $n|a$ or $n|b$, or both. Now **assume** $n$ is composite, i.e., $n$ is not prime. Then, from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $n$ can be written as a unique product of primes $p_1, p_2,\ldots, p_k$, that is, $$ n = p_1p_2 \ldots p_k, k \in \mathbb{N}. $$

Since $p_1|n$ and $n|ab$, it follows that $p_1|ab$. Also, since $n \neq 0$, we have $\lvert p_1 \rvert < \lvert n \rvert$. But this is a contradiction, because $n$ is the smallest natural number that divides $ab$. Thus, our assumption of $n$ being composite must be false. Therefore, $n$ is prime. $\text{Q.E.D.}$

Is this proof correct? Please provide a critique.

Comment: In the Theorem, $n$ is given, you can't choose it. You should play with choosing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLewy, you are right. I'm embarrassed. Should I delete the question? I found a correct proof online.

Comment: Take $n$ given and not prime. Then $n=c\cdot d$ with $c,d>1$. now choose $a,b$ such that the property wouldn't hold. You can do as you wish with the question.

Comment: @Sassy You don't need to look elsewhere since there are plenty of proofs here, e.g. [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205002/242)